# List of dictionary need to split and take first only value after split

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionary in Python that i want to convert to another list after i split the value in the dictionary and take only first value after the split.

```
myList = [
  {'name': 'CN=John,Li', 
   'type': 'Agent', 
   'isMember': False},
  {'name': 'CN=Moses,Somewhere', 
   'type': 'Worker', 
   'isMember': True},
  {'name': 'CN=David, Something', 
   'type': 'Agent', 
   'isMember': False}
]


required_fields = ['name', 'isMember']
```

I'm looking for desired output after splitting the values

```
myList = [
  {'name': 'John', 
   'isMember': False},
  {'name': 'Moses', 
   'isMember': True},
  {'name': 'David', 
   'isMember': False}
]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

A small helper function to find the `CN=...` part from the name, and a list comprehension to loop over `myList`:

```
import re


def get_cn(name):
    return re.search("CN=([^,]+)", name).group(1)


my_list = [...]

new_list = [
    {'name': get_cn(x['name']), 'isMember': x['isMember']}
    for x 
    in my_list
]

print(new_list)
```

This outputs

```
[{'name': 'John', 'isMember': False}, {'name': 'Moses', 'isMember': True}, {'name': 'David', 'isMember': False}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in single liner -->

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(myList)):
    new_list.append({"name": re.search("CN=([^,]+)", myList[i]['name']).group(1), \
                     "isMember":myList[i]['isMember']})
print(new_list)
```